# TIdFtpClient - handling specific error at the server side

Tags: delphi, indy

Clients periodically send data to server TIdFtpServer in passive mode.
In one client machine, where network sometime is breaking I got message:

EIdReplyRFCError : File status okay; about to open data connection.

And next commands also throw exception like:
EIdReplyRFCError : Requested action aborted: local error in processing.

When any EIdException apperar then clear socket like:

```
if Assigned(FFtp.IOHandler) then
begin
  FFtp.IOHandler.InputBuffer.Clear;
  FFtp.IOHandler.Close;
end;
FFtp.KillDataChannel;
```

But client cannot longer send data, still EIdReplyRDCError is throwing and I must restart Server FTP. After restart then client reconnect succesfully and can send data.
In the server side, I don't logged any uncatched exceptions.

I tried also at the server side, kill clients which no send data over 20 minutes:

```
try
  T := FFtpServ.Contexts.LockList;
  for I := 0 to T.Count - 1 do
  if TIdFtpServerContext(T[I]).Data <> nil then
  begin
    Cl := TFtpCl(TIdFtpServerContext(T[I]).Data);

    Minutes := MinutesBetween(Cl.LastPing, Now);
    if Minutes >= 20 then
    begin
      if(Assigned(TIdFtpServerContext(T[I]).Connection.IOHandler)) then
      begin
        TIdFtpServerContext(T[I]).Connection.IOHandler.InputBuffer.Clear;
        TIdFtpServerContext(T[I]).Connection.IOHandler.Close;
      end;
      TIdFtpServerContext(T[I]).KillDataChannel;
    end;
  end;
finally
  DM.FFtpServ.Contexts.UnLockList;
end;
```

But in this approach often I got AccessViolation exception.

Any idea to solve this problem?

Comment: " I must restart Server FTP." - why ? you should restart the connection. Disconnect client and connect him again.

Comment: Also what does that "Access Violation" mean ? At which line does it happen ? when accessing which object on that line ? Is it when reading or when writings ? What is the error text given ? Please so not conceal your information. Read http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#code - that is great FAQ

Answer (score 0):

After Contexts.UnLockList. I think in the client-pool thread exception is throwing.

How properly disconnect specified client at the server side?

Comment: DON'T call `IOHandler.Clear()`, `IOHandler.Close()`, or `Context.KillDataChannel()` on the server side.  Let `TIdFTPServer` handle all of that for you. All you need to do is call `Connection.Disconnect()`, nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe suggests the FTP communication has gotten out of sync.  `TIdFTP` is processing server responses in the wrong order.  The best you can do is just have the client disconnect and re-connect.  You do not have to do anything on the server side.